# International acceptance of separatist movements

Tags: united-nations, catalonia, kashmir

If there exists an active separatist movement within an existing nation and there are reports of oppression of self expression by the government, what possible actions could be taken by international bodies like the United Nations.

Would it be possible for people of Kashmir to appeal to the UN for holding a referendum, or for the people of Catalonia to appeal for accepting their referendum?

Comment: I feel like there was already an answer somewhere on the site addressing this, but can't find it